# How can I link local files (Excel Sheets/Word Docs/Videos etc.) saved on my laptop to Diagrams.net/Draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I would like to link some excel tables or even add them on Draw.io.

These files are saved on my laptop, but I don't know how to link them to the diagram. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution but you could try the following workaround: upload these files to Google Drive, grab the links, select a shape in the draw.io editor, right mouse click > Edit link and drag URLs.

For an Excel file, you should export it as .csv first and then do all the steps described above (cs can be imported to draw.io).